# .txt to SQlite3 with C++

Tags: c++, sqlite

I want to read data from txt file and insert it into SQlite database table with C++. I prepared a code but it doesn't work.

Example line from my txt file is follows;
',1417392060.000000','1.245430','1.2456','1.24469','1.245000'

And code;

```js
   sqlite3 *db;
   char *zErrMsgt = 0;
   int  rct;
   int  rch;
   int rchi;
  
 rct = sqlite3_open("final.db", &db);
   if( rct ){
      fprintf(stderr, "Can't open database: %s\n", sqlite3_errmsg(db));
      exit(0);
   }else{
      fprintf(stdout, "Opened database successfully\n");
   }
string resline;
ifstream res("Res.txt");
while(getline(res,resline)){
   string sqlli = "INSERT into FOREXNEW(DATE,OPEN,HIGH,LOW,CLOSE) VALUES ("getline(res,resline)");";
   rchi = sqlite3_exec(db, sqlli.c_str(), callback, 0, &zErrMsgt);
   if( rchi != SQLITE_OK ){
     cout << "SQL error:" <<  zErrMsgt;
     sqlite3_free(zErrMsgt);
   }}

sqlite3_close(db);
```

Any alternate suggestions and solutions will be appreciated as well:) Thank you.

Comment: Please indent your code properly. What do you mean by "it doesn't work"? Does it raise an error, terminates without taking effect?

Comment: It dees not even compile, due to specification errors.

Comment: Is it all the code? Could you post the whole file and the errors you are getting?

Comment: It is just an excerpt my whole code is very long, thats why I am not posting it, I will edit the post now,

Comment: This line looks a bit suspicious: `string sqlli = "INSERT into FOREXNEW(DATE,OPEN,HIGH,LOW,CLOSE) VALUES ("getline(res,resline)");";`

Comment: Yes, I tried to insert one line by line, but it didn't compiled, I don't now how to compile in other ways,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Getline doesn't return a string; it copies it to the variable passed in the second parameter. Change the erroneous line:

```
   string sqlli = "INSERT into FOREXNEW(DATE,OPEN,HIGH,LOW,CLOSE) VALUES ("getline(res,resline)");";
```

to:

```
   string sqlli = "INSERT into FOREXNEW(DATE,OPEN,HIGH,LOW,CLOSE) VALUES ("+resline+");";
```

And check if it works.